# How to get timezone strings from timezone string columns?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

**1** I have a CSV containing a column data["timestamps1"] of GMT-timezone strings in this format:

2020-02-28T12:53:47.167Z

**2** I want to get a new column with strings of the timezone in another tz-time which is Europe/Berlin, the format doesn't matter that much, e.g.

2020-02-28 13:53:47

How can i do that? I tried already parsing dates

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
path = "timestamps.csv"                           
data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=";", parse_dates= ["timestamps1"])

data['timestamps1_new'] = data['timestamps1'].dt.tz_localize('GMT').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

Then i get the error *"Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert."*
When I do not parse dates, i get *"Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"*. Even when I manipulate the string in this way, the error occurs:

```
data["timestamps1"] = data["timestamps1"].str[:-5]
data["timestamps1"] = data.timestamps1.replace("T"," ",regex=True)
```

Here are some example data:

```
data = {'timestamps': ['2020-11-28T13:14:57.463Z','2020-11-28T13:14:57.603Z','2020-11-28T13:14:57.618Z']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: your format `2020-02-28T12:53:47.167Z` (ISO8601) automatically gets parsed to aware datetime (tzinfo set, UTC). so you simply need to convert: `data['timestamps1_new'] = data['timestamps1'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` parses [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format with `Z` denoting UTC directly to aware datetime (it "knows" it's in UTC...):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'timestamps': ['2020-11-28T13:14:57.463Z','2020-11-28T13:14:57.603Z','2020-11-28T13:14:57.618Z']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# you skip this step by setting 'parse_dates' in read_csv
data['timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamps'])

print(data['timestamps'])
0   2020-11-28 13:14:57.463000+00:00
1   2020-11-28 13:14:57.603000+00:00
2   2020-11-28 13:14:57.618000+00:00
Name: timestamps, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

So you can convert directly:

```
data['timeGermany'] = data['timestamps'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')

print(data['timeGermany'])
0   2020-11-28 14:14:57.463000+01:00
1   2020-11-28 14:14:57.603000+01:00
2   2020-11-28 14:14:57.618000+01:00
Name: timeGermany, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Comment: That's exactly it, I get it, thanks a lot!